# Access Sass Variables from PHP

Tags: php, sass

I have a `_colors.scss` file, which includes that:

```
$colors: (
  red: #ff0000,
  green: #00ff00,
  blue: #0000ff
);

//much more declarations down here
```

I really would like to access those variables from php. So I required `leafo/scssphp` and us that snippet:

```
$compiler = new Compiler();
$result = $compiler->compile(file_get_contents('_colors.scss'));
```

Than `$result` is an empty string, what makes sense, but I cannot figure out how to get the variables.

```
$compiler->getVariables();
```

returns an empty array and all other methods don't seam to do what I am after… Any Ideas?

Comment: `leafo/scssphp` has nothing built-in that could do that. You'll need to either hack the source code or implement a workaround using Custom Functions

Comment: The documentation states that the return value of the compile is css. So you would still have to parse the colors from css after compiling!

Comment: I doubt you can get the contents of a map. You could use javascript or Jquery to add a class to a certain function. The class would contain your color